# How to break out of recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a recursive function where I'm trying to flatten a list of nested lists. I want to stop the recursive function as soon as I find an integer. An example list would be: `[[[1.2, 2.3, 3.3], [4.3, [[5]]]], 6.3]`

```
def flatten(arr):
    for elem in arr:
        if isinstance(elem, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(elem, (str, bytes)):
            return flatten(elem)
        else:
            if not isinstance(elem, float):
                # break out of the recursion
```

How do I get it to stop as soon as I find an int?

Comment: By "stop", do you mean discard the results, or something else? Please explain what you would like to happen. Also, you say you want to stop when you find an integer, but your code indicates you want to stop when you find something other than an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `return` at that point, if you want to propagate the result back up.

For instance, if you want to return the first non-float found:

```py
def flatten(arr):
    for elem in arr:
        if isinstance(elem, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(elem, (str, bytes)):
            res = flatten(elem)
            if res is not None: # add this if you want to return the first one
                break
        else:
            if not isinstance(elem, float):
                return elem

    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop the for loop, just use a *break*, the code would be like that:

```
def flatten(arr):
for elem in arr:
    if isinstance(elem, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(elem, (str, bytes)):
        return flatten(elem)
    else:
        if not isinstance(elem, int):
            break
```

Instead of using break, you could just return the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'break' statement.

```
def flatten(arr):
    for elem in arr:
        if isinstance(elem, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(elem, (str, bytes)):
            return flatten(elem)
        else:
            if not isinstance(elem, int):
                # break out of the recursion
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is lil bit off but I can guess what you're trying to do

```
 return flatten(elem)
```

flatten() Will call flatten() itself, when it doesnt find an integer
it's return value simulation will be like this:

1(first round).----> **return flatten()**

2. -----------------> **return (return flatten())**
3. -----------------> **return (return (return flatten()))**

4.(integer found) -> **return (return (intFound))**

in order to make 3's **return flatten()** to 4's **intFOund**

u need to return flatten() function with integer like this:

```
  if not isinstance(elem, int):
      return elem
```

5. ------------->  **return (intFound)**

finally you have ur **intFound** returned out of function